# Target text to viewer (Not camera)

Tags: 3d-view, text-object

Is it possible to target text objects to the viewer (In viewport mode)?

I know I can target text to a camera, but I am finding it convenient to move the viewport around my object and use the Viewport Render function. But, when I do that, the text does not follow and I have to change its orientation manually.

Comment: I don't think so but if you enable the Lock Camera to View option the camera view will work  as a viewer

Comment: @moonboots That is not perfect but will work for me.  Thanks!